Boundary Conditions of a SABR PDE
I am looking to solve a sabr partial differential equation numerically using finite volume method, but I don't seem to find any information about the boundary condition to apply. Below is the form of the PDE that I'm looking to solve numerically.


The boundary condition / terminal condition is the payoff of the claim / derivative. For instance for a European call option the boundary condition is $u(T,F_T) = (F_T - K)_+$.

which book or article did you get this image from?
